# wait for animation to complete and then execute the code

Tags: android, animation

I am using a custom animation library.

The zoomin animation works well

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(700).playOn(retView);
```

But then, when it comes to deleting the row from the listview (also from the sqlite), the items gets deleted without zoomout animation.
When I remove the code for deletion, I can see the zoomout animation.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d("HirakDebug", "tCA delete button pressed");
      String row = row_id;
      YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomOut).duration(700).playOn(retView);
      taskslist.closeAnimate(pos);
      tasksDatabaseOperations.deleteItemWithTask(row_id);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      cursor.requery();
   }
```

How can I do such that first animation is completed and then the deletion occurs?

Answer (score 3):

```
You could try the follow, calling the delete methods after the animation has ended.

     YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomOut)
    .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
     @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

       }
       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
         tasksDatabaseOperations.deleteItemWithTask(row_id);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         cursor.requery();
       }
       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

       }
       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

       }
       })
    .duration(700)
    .playOn(retView);
```